# Best practice for writing reusable documentation

Tags: documentation, documentation-generation, reusability, docbook, dita

Our company has a rather small product line but the usage can be quite complex.

The current situation is that the (internal and external) documentation is spread over various places: Wiki, Adobe Indesign files, docs, text files, inline documentation in the code, help texts in the webinterface of our products etc. The documentation is written by a small group of developers but keeping track of all changes is nearly impossible if you want to update all of the other sources.

In general, we want to provide the following kinds of documentation (sorted by raising complexity).

- Quick start guide
- User guide
- Help texts in webinterface
- Administration manual
- Training manual
- Internal documentation (for developers)

Much of the content is the same for all of the manuals (general information), some of the content is just in the last three types and the internal documentation should contain all of the contents.

I've had a look at some tools which are often recommended on stackoverflow (namely DITA, docBook, pandoc, doxygen, Sphinx). Except for DITA (or DITA OT) and docBook, none of the tools seem to focus on reusable content. But those two tools also seem to be very complex and user unfriendly.

Of course it would be possible to use just LaTeX and include just the parts suited for the type of documentation you want to build. But this seems like a workaround solution to me.

So I am wondering:

- Is there a best practice on how to write reusable documentation?
- How do big(ger) companies manage their documentation?
- Is there a way to have all documentation in a single place and compile different versions for different target groups without handling the changes by hand?

For internal documentation it would be nice to include parts from the code but it's not mandatory. It would be also nice to use version control (git) to maintain the content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for a *single-sourcing* documentation tool, such as [Author-It](http://www.author-it.com/) or [MadCap Flare](https://www.madcapsoftware.com). These let you write topics once and then embed those topics in multiple documents (so when you make changes, you only need to do it one place).

They also make it very easy to generate multiple output formats from the same content, e.g. an HTML version of your admin manual for your website and a PDF one to ship with the product.

Hiring a technical author to help you get set up is probably a good investment.

Comment: Thank you. "single source documentation" was the keyword I was missing. I found another helpful thread on SO relating to this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1283348/single-source-documentation-tool

Comment: I'm glad it helped. Please consider marking this as the answer by clicking on the tick symbol. Note that questions asking about what tools are available aren't a great fit for Stack Overflow and are likely to get closed (since they tend to generate long lists of subjective options rather than definitive answers) -- although it wasn't me that downvoted you ;-)

Answer (score 1):

DITA is made for that and offers many reuse mechanisms, like keyrefs, conkeyrefs, filters, etc. You can find an introduction video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yxRv5n9w0I4&t=1526s), which explains these mechanisms. You have to carefully weigh up, whether it is a good idea to rely on a proprietary tool/format for your documentation, (e.g. use Author-It or MadCap or any other competing tool). This may be a one-way street without any return points. If you want to switch your documentation toolset, e.g. because your vendor increases prices or stops supporting your tool, you have a problem. DITA is probably more expensive, but it is an open standard.